# subnetting on the given ip address 201.40.58.0/24

Tags: routes, subnet

you are given the ip address block of 201.40.58.0/24 now design the subnet for 49,27,1145 hosts group so that ip address wastage is minimum. also show network address, firsthost, last host and broad cast address.

confused in  should i put the host in acending or decending order to calculate and what will be the network address , boradcast address, last host and first host.

each calculation done make different one while doing on acending and decending both . got confused

network address broadcast address, first host , last host for the given question

Answer (score 0):

### Solution to this problem involves [supernetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernetwork):

To start, you must sort your number of hosts from biggest to smallest:
**1145, 49, 27**

Then, you calculate how big should your supernet be:

So you basically need to calculate the mask for each number of hosts (substracted `2` because of network and broadcast address):

- 1145 :

[image: 2^{10} - 2 < 49 \leqslant \textbf{2}^\textbf{11}-2]

mask = 32 - 11 = 21

- 49:

[image: 2^{5} - 2 < 49 \leqslant \textbf{2}^\textbf{6}-2]

mask = 32 - 6 = 26

- 27:

[image: 2^{4} - 2 < 27 \leqslant \textbf{2}^\textbf{5}-2]

mask = 32 - 5 = 27

---

Knowing the values of the masks, we can calculate the mask of the supernet:

First, calculate the total number of addresses needed for the supernetwork:

[image: {2}^{11} + {2}^{6} + {2}^{5} = 2048 + 64 + 32 = 2144]

Comparing this value to the power of `2` as previously:

[image: 2^{11} - 2 < 2144 \leqslant \textbf{2}^\textbf{12}-2]

mask = 32 - 12 = 20

So we know the mask of the entire supernetwork, now we can get the network address:

201.40.58.0/24 net address has to be changed due to the new mask (all the bits that are not within mask has to be 0's). So in binary:

```
                      mask = 20
                      | 
                      v
11001001.00101000.0011|1010.00000000
```

After conversion (all the bits to the right of mask are zero):

`11001001.00101000.00110000.00000000`

Converting each octet back to decimal, we get the following network address:

##### 201.40.48.0/24

From now on, this supernetwork address can be easily divided into subnets.

---

For:

- 1145 hosts:

`network address = 201.40.48.0/21`

broadcast address is the negation of all but the mask bits, in binary:

```
                       mask = 21
                       | 
                       v
11001001.00101000.00110|000.00000000
                       |
                       v
11001001.00101000.00110|111.11111111
```

To decimal:

`broadcast address = 201.40.55.255/21`

Knowing that:

`first host address = network address + 1`

and:

`last host address = broadcast address - 1`

We have:

```
first host address = 201.40.48.1/21
last host address = 201.40.55.254/21
```

- 49 hosts:

Because of the fact that:

`next network address = previous broadcast address + 1`

We get:

`network address = 201.40.56.0/26`

And then, as with normal subnetting, we get:

```
first host address = 201.40.56.1/26
last host address = 201.40.56.62/26
broadcast address = 201.40.56.63/26
```

- 27 hosts:

Calculating it as previously:

```
network address = 201.40.56.64/27
first host address = 201.40.56.65/27
last host address = 201.40.56.94/27
broadcast address = 201.40.56.95/27
```

Comment: what about network address for 1145 host be 201.40.56.0
and broad cast address be 201.40.63.255 and continuing with it

Comment: @UtshavAdhikari I don't know what you mean. For 1145 hosts network address is `201.40.48.0/21` and broadcast is `201.40.55.255/21`